HMAC with appended key
Length extension attack can be used if HMAC is implemented with key prepended (sha-1/2, but not SHA3).
What do we gain in HMAC security by using inner/outer key as opposed to simply APPEND the key to the end and then calculate hash?
Orig post why prepend is a problem.
Key at start or end of HMAC

HMAC actually does prepend the key. It isn't vulnerable to the length extension attack because of the double hashing. The reason for ipad/opad is to create independent keys. Finally, appending the key is a bad idea because the security is reduced to the collision resistance of the hash function, whereas HMAC maintains some security without collision resistance. Note that keyed BLAKE2 and KMAC also prepend the key and aren't vulnerable to length extension attacks.

Thanks, what you said makes sense.

I'm glad. There are some good answers on here that I'd recommend reading that go into more detail. Secret suffix, secret suffix again, double hashing against length extension attacks, prefix MAC, ipad/opad purpose, ipad/opad choice, etc. And the HMAC RFC and papers.
